# Difference between calling a method via Class.method(instance) and instance.method()

Tags: python, methods

In various tutorials I've seen it claimed that calling a method using `instance.method()` is syntactically equivalent to `Class.method(instance)`. I was also researching what 'method binding' is and the official python documentation states:

> "When an instance attribute is referenced that isn’t a data attribute,
>   its class is searched. If the name denotes a valid class attribute
>   that is a function object, a method object is created by packing
>   (pointers to) the instance object and the function object just found
>   together in an abstract object: this is the method object. When the
>   method object is called with an argument list, a new argument list is
>   constructed from the instance object and the argument list, and the
>   function object is called with this new argument list."

Based on this description, it appears only the `instance.method()` syntax would result in an 'abstract method object' being created because the 'instance attribute is being referenced'. If that is the case, how are the two expressions syntactically equivalent?

Comment: Being exact, they are not syntactically equivalent, since they have a different syntax. But they have the same result. With some steps in between, `instance.method()` calls `class.method(instance)`. In the end it's just a bad usage of "syntax".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the creation of that abstract object is only an intermediate step.  In the quote you gave, the end result is:

> a new argument list is constructed from the instance object and the argument list, and the function object is called with this new argument list

In other words, in the end, the function object that "is" the method is called with the instance as the first argument and the rest of the arguments passed along.  That is also what happens when you call the method yourself with the instance as the first argument.

Comment: Hmm I think I understand now. So is using Class.method(instance) technically "faster" because it skips the intermediate step of creating the abstract object and generating the new argument list?

Comment: @user2154633: Possibly, but why do you care about any of this?